# Set Webpage to Readonly only?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, readonly

I have a webpage with a lot of inputs, and would like to set them all to read only, or disabled = false because i have **Datepickers** and would like them disabled to.

I think the best way would to do it though a style sheet, but i have almost no exp with CSS Stlesheets.

I am using JQuery if there is any options there, else is there some html or some styling in the CSS i can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't need to use the form, why don't you just print the values to HTML instead of inserting them into form elements ?

Comment: The form can still be view, and is saved into a database, but after its finalised, no changes may be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make all the inputs in the page to readonly:

```
$(':input').prop('readonly',true);
```

In order to disable:

```
$(':input').prop('disabled',true);
```

Hope this helps.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, will this also disable my datepickers?

Comment: @Pomster: Your datepickers are basically inputs so yes.

Comment: Yes thanks this is perfect :), exsactly what i wanted :D, i need one button no disabled, $('#btnPrint').prop('ensabled',true); work?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make all of your **input fields** on you webpage set to `readonly`, you can use this:

```
$(':input').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

To **disable** you can use:

```
$(':input').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Hey thanks this works Really well, i just have 3 textbox's that have data pickers, do you know how i could disable them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make all of your input type=text fields on your webpage set to disable

```
$(":input[type=text]").attr("disabled", true);
```

If you want make disable specific 3 textbox

```
$("#date1,#date2,#date2").attr("disabled", true);
```

If you want to make all of your input type=text fields on your webpage set to readonly

```
$(":input[type=text]").attr("readonly", true);
```

If you want make readonly specific 3 textbox

```
$("#date1,#date2,#date2").attr("readonly", true);
```